# Is it possible to get a link to an internal TestFlight build?

Tags: ios, testflight, testflight-public-link

This question relates to TestFlight on iOS and Test Versions for Internal Testers only (so NOT public invite links for Beta testers)

I would like to simulate the process of onboarding, from an invite email, to installation, to first launch.  It seems this is a bit of a chicken and the egg problem with Apple, since I can't provide an appstore link (so to install it) to an app that's not on the app store.

I could do this with TestFlight IF it would be a public beta with public invite link.

However, we are at v0.1 and don't really need/want Apple's review process at this stage, because this just adds a lot of bureaucracy on their side that we don't want to concern ourselves with (yet).

So, assuming I'm a user with the Testflight app installed on my iPhone AND I am in the internal testers group, is there a URL scheme that would take me to the new test version's installation page?

Or at least, is there a URL scheme for testflight?

Answer (score 1):

No - There is no way to get the installation link for internal testers. Instead you can use enterprise account to generate the distribution ipa and host it somewhere like beta family or diawi or in your own server.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you sort of can.  It involves using an unofficial URL Scheme to the Testflight app, [outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667467/opening-testflight-app-from-another-app-and-deep-link-to-specific-app).  It assumes your internal testers' devices are registered and they have Testflight installed.