# Launching TestFlight from in an iOS app (deep linking)

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, testflight

I'd like to be able to launch TestFlight from within an app (which in beta), to let people update to a newer version of my app when I detect that one exists.

It used to be that the URL scheme `itms-beta://` could be invoked to launch TestFlight, so that the following Swift code could be used (see [this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667467/opening-testflight-app-from-another-app-and-deep-link-to-specific-app):

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "itms-beta://")!)
```

(As of iOS 9.0 it was also a requirement to add a corresponding entry for the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in `Info.plist`.)

Unfortunately, this no longer appears to function in iOS 14.
Any idea how to achieve it in iOS 14?

Comment: Did you solve this somehow? Could it be that the user doesn't have TestFlight installed?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't solve it, @HarounHajem - I eventually gave up. But I do know it was not a matter of having TestFlight installed. I would still love a solution.

Comment: Hmm.. We are currently looking into it. If we find something i will post it here. It's strange that Apple cant publicly announce any deeplinks for TestFlight. Couldn't we as the dev community open up a request to apple?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it out with iOS 15 and it didn't do anything in the simulator but did when I tested on a device, so I'll need to look into it more as soon as I have a sec, @HarounHajem! I would think that it would be something that Apple would appreciate and want to encourage - an app giving a nudge for users to update - or at least document how to do it.

Comment: Seems to be working in iOS 16, I am using `itms-beta://<app-name>` to redirect user to TestFlight app